# How do I fix error when installing pyInstaller

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd, installation, pyinstaller

I use [windows](/questions/tagged/windows) and [python](/questions/tagged/python) v3.8.1. I am trying to [install](/questions/tagged/install) [pyinstaller](/questions/tagged/pyinstaller), but when I type:

```
pip install pyinstaller
```

into the [cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd) shell, I get this error message:

> ```
>  Traceback (most recent call last):
>  File "c:\program files\python38\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
>    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
>  File "c:\program files\python38\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
>    exec(code, run_globals)
>  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\Scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
> TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
python3 -m pip install stdlib_list --user
```

Otherwise try to uninstall and reinstall PIP

Answer (score 0):

Try installing using the following command
`python3 -m pip install <library_name_here> --user`

Answer (score 0):

Check this, using: pip list

- There is a setuptools module installed. If not: py -m pip install setuptools

  I remember latest version is 44.0

Then try to install, using:  py -m pip install PyInstaller

```
 Latest version is 3.5
```

> Anyway, [PyInstaller](https://www.pyinstaller.org/) doesn't support Python 3.8.x.